# How to group and collect data in PostgreSQL by date periods?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is a demo data:

```
create table Invoices (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR,
    customer_id INT,
    total_amount FLOAT,
    state VARCHAR,
    invoice_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO Invoices
    (id, name, customer_id, total_amount, state, invoice_date)
VALUES
    (1,  'INV/2020/0001', 2, 100, 'posted', '2020-04-05'),
    (2,  'INV/2020/0002', 1, 100, 'draft',  '2020-04-05'),
    (3,  'INV/2020/0003', 2, 100, 'draft',  '2020-05-24'),
    (4,  'INV/2020/0004', 1, 100, 'posted', '2020-05-25'),
    (5,  'INV/2020/0005', 2, 100, 'posted', '2020-06-05'),
    (6,  'INV/2020/0006', 1, 100, 'posted', '2020-07-05'),
    (7,  'INV/2020/0007', 1, 100, 'draft',  '2020-08-24'),
    (8,  'INV/2020/0008', 1, 100, 'posted', '2020-08-25'),
    (9,  'INV/2020/0009', 1, 100, 'posted', '2020-09-05'),
    (10, 'INV/2020/0010', 1, 100, 'draft',  '2020-09-05'),
    (11, 'INV/2020/0011', 2, 100, 'draft',  '2020-10-24'),
    (12, 'INV/2020/0012', 1, 100, 'posted', '2020-10-25'),
    (13, 'INV/2020/0013', 2, 100, 'posted', '2020-11-05'),
    (14, 'INV/2020/0014', 1, 100, 'posted', '2020-11-05'),
    (15, 'INV/2020/0015', 2, 100, 'draft',  '2020-11-24'),
    (16, 'INV/2020/0016', 1, 100, 'posted', '2020-11-25')
```

I have a query that computes a sum of all posted invoices for customer with id = 1

```
SELECT sum(total_amount), customer_id 
    FROM Invoices 
        WHERE state = 'posted' AND customer_id = 1  
    GROUP BY customer_id
```

I need to group the data (sum(total_amount)) by 3 time periods - 2 or 3 months each (2 or 3 needs to be able to change by changing the number in the query. I want to pass it as a parameter to the query from python code).
Also I need to get the average sums of the period.
Can you help me please?

Expected output for period = 2 months is:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
| Period_1_sum | Period_2_sum | Period_3_sum |  Avg   |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
|          300 |          300 |          100 | 233.33 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. Can you please add the expected output?  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Hello @a_horse_with_no_name, thank's for your reply. I have updated the question with the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for that:

```
SELECT customer_id, 
       sum(total_amount) as total_amount,
       sum(total_amount) filter (where invoice_date >= date '2020-04-01' and invoice_date < date '2020-07-01') as period_1_sum,
       sum(total_amount) filter (where invoice_date >= date '2020-07-01' and invoice_date < date '2020-10-01') as period_2_sum,
       sum(total_amount) filter (where invoice_date >= date '2020-10-01' and invoice_date < date '2021-01-01') as period_3_sum
FROM Invoices 
WHERE state = 'posted' 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

By changing the filter condition you can control which rows are aggregated for each period.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=422294be770ad5490f14e4b6d35d678a)

Comment: period sums returns null values https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0

Comment: Then your WHERE condition in the FILTER clause doesn't match any rows. The values I chose are just examples. You need to adjust them to whatever periods you want

Comment: It is the same if I delete WHERE condition

Comment: maybe there is some problem with date column in demo data?

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=422294be770ad5490f14e4b6d35d678a

Comment: very weird! Maybe something wrong with my fiddle. On my local database it works fine! Thank you!
Also, does it possible to get the average from the periods columns as an extra column?

Comment: Hi! @a_horse_with_no_name, Did you changed the query?